# jQuery mobile, pageshow event for multiple pages

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I've got two pages, test1.html and test2.html. Every time when one of these pages gets visible I want to execute some code.

Here are the two pages:

test1.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head><body>

<div data-role="page" id="test1">

    <div data-role="content">

    <a href="test2.html" data-role="button">jump to test2</a>

    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('pageshow', '#test1', function (data) {
    alert('pageshow test1');
});

</script>
</body></html>
```

test2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head><body>

<div data-role="page" id="test2">

    <div data-role="content">

    <a href="test1.html" data-role="button">jump to test1</a>

    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pageshow', '#test2', function (data) {
    alert('pageshow test2');
});
</script>

</body></html>
```

When I start with test1.html I get the alert just for test1 (also every time when I return to it) but never for test2.html.

What I need is a show-handler which is different for each page.

Answer (score 2):

### Available solutions

#### Solution 1

First, remove javascript code from page **`BODY`** and put it into a single js file. That new js file should be placed into **`HEAD`** after js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js initialization.

Something like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

In your case jQuery mobile is loading a second **HTML** file, but only this part:

```
<div data-role="page" id="test2">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="test1.html" data-role="button">jump to test1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will be loaded with ajax into the **DOM** structure. This is the main reason why second page script is not executed.

#### Solution 2

Second solution would be to use a **`rel="external"`** attribute in your links, it will force page reload every time new page is opened.

```
<a href="test1.html" data-role="button" rel="external">jump to test1</a>
```

No matter what, if possible never use **`SCRIPT`** tag inside page **`BODY`**, it will work but at the same time it can cause additional problems

### More information

If you want to find out more about this problem, how to solve it + examples take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)** I made in my **personal blog**. This article talks directly about this topic so I hope you will not see it as a try in self promotion.